# Xcode application uploader suddenly saying icons are missing

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, app-store

I updated to macOS High Sierra and now Xcode is suddenly saying an app's icons are totally missing when preparing for upload to iTunes Connect. This is an error returned by the iTMS service after the upload, not Xcode 9.

> Missing recommended icon file - The bundle does not contain an app
>   icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png
>   format

I exported the IPA locally and of course (and as expected) the icons are all there, as nothing has changed in that configuration since our last successful binary upload, which did not render this error.

To me this seems like an iTMS issue, but I have no way of knowing unless there's a workaround. Anyone know?

Comment: Check your App Icon folder for the exact image for which error is produced. And if the image exists then check the size and the extension of image. I also had faced this issue once. And it was there with the size of image.

Comment: @KrishnaDattShukla It's all of the images that are displaying this error, basically. They've all suddenly stopped being recognized at once.

Comment: just remove the app icon assets from project. make a clean. Import icons again. And try again. Maybe its just bcoz of updating OS and XCode.

Comment: You have forgot to add the 120x120 png file into the app icon.

Comment: @CGD "You have forgot to add the 120x120 png file into the app icon." go back and read the question since you clearly didn't, thanks

Comment: @BenGuild The exact same thing happened to me after upgrading to High Sierra - did you find a fix?

Comment: @nambatee The workaround is here: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/86290  — scroll down to the post by "stubyte"

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same error when using Xcode 10 to build and upload an existing project previously built and submitted with Xcode 9. All icon sizes were there in the catalog.

My solution was to delete the asset catalog and re-create it using the exact icons that were already in the current asset catalog.

Cleaned, Rebuilt, uploaded again and no error.